# Accessing GCloud resources on socks proxy

Tags: hadoop, proxy, gcloud, socks, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to access GCloud resources, in particular DataProc's Hadoop UI for Resource Manager which runs on port 8088.

I have the following cluster in GCloud,

[image]

And from my local I have created a socks proxy through the following:

```
C:\Users\Sujith>gcloud compute ssh "myhadoop-m" --zone=us-east4-c
--project=project1234 -- -D 10000 -N
```

which successfully creates a tunnel authenticating through public key

Followed it by opening the chrome, using the tunnel that was created above to launch the resource manager

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe "http://myhadoop-m:8088" --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:10000" --host-resolver-rules="Map * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost --user-data-dir=/tmp/myhadoop-m
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing quote in `--host-resolver-rules` parameter value.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe "http://myhadoop-m:8088" --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:10000" --host-resolver-rules="Map * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost" --user-data-dir=/tmp/myhadoop-m
```

Comment: Good eye,  for some reason Windows Powershell has an issue understanding --usr-data-dir, I created the folder structure manually to see if that makes any difference,  I eventually tried with bash shell and it worked.  +1.